# Azure Data Factory data flow timezone conversion problem

Tags: azure, etl, azure-data-factory

I was trying to convert a timezone from CST to UTC inside a data flow. A quick google gave me that CST is in UTC-6:00, so it should add 6 hours.

The following derived column function for some reason only added 5 hours:

```
toUTC(localDatetime, 'CST')
```

Moreover, CurrentUTC('CST') Gave me the correct 6 hours difference, so I had to rewrite this function like this:

```
LocalDatetime + hours(toInteger((currentUTC('CST') - currentUTC()) / 1000 / 60 / 60)) 
// Minus between timestamps gives difference in milliseconds
```

Is this intended behavior? I am worried that when the timezone "shifts" this code will break, so using toUTC would be the best solution, but for some reason it gives incorrect results now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[toUTC()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expressions-usage#toutc)  converts a datetime to UTC time zone based on the Daylight-Saving Time effectiveness.

When you are converting from CST to UCT, if your date falls when Daylight saving is effective, then it adds +5 to your date else adds +6 to your date.

Example:

[image]

Derived column expression: `toUTC(toTimestamp(Date_UTC), 'CST')`

[image]